# Hose for connecting 3/8 inch nipple

Tags: plumbing

I have a hose that connects a water pump to a pressure tank.

The nipple is 3/8" I need to connect a longer hose, but all the 3/8 "faucet" hoses that I've found are too small for the 3/8 nipple.

[image: hose with nipple]

Comment: Need a different shop then, tap or faucet hoses are not large enough.

Comment: That is water supply line for a faucet or water fixture and not the correct thing to use for a water pump/pressure tank. It may burst or cause issues with the pump having to work to hard for the small hose.

Comment: That’s the size most refrigerators take, for a main water supply that is quite small. You should be able to find them up to 25’ or so on line. Yup just searched for 3/8 refrigerator water home desperate had 25’ just like the one you have for 19 and change , Amazon had a PEX version for less 25’ long.

Comment: @Alaska Man this hose is actually from the water pump.

Answer (score 1):

. The 3/8" hoses that you have will not thread to a 3/8" pipe nipple since the connectors are for 3/8" compression fittings which are different than 3/8" pipe. You need to find/buy flexible hoses with connectors that connect to 3/8" pipe. Talk to the people in the store that you are purchasing the hoses from to get the correct ones. Also, add a picture of what you are trying to accomplish. You may be able to adapt washing machine hoses or something similar for your use.

Comment: Makes sense that those hoses use compression fittings as opposed to "brass pipe" fittings. I just wanted to extend the length of the original hose. Searched the hardware store, but couldn't find any other type of hose that would fit. I think 1/2" might work, but would need more adapters.